# Why does Delphi 10 Seattle use CPU in 'Windows Driver Foundation - User mode driver.... host process' when VM resumed, with File Not Found errors

Tags: delphi, vmware, delphi-10-seattle

I've installed Delphi 10 Seattle in a Windows 10 VM in VMWare Workstation 10. Starting VM from cold it all runs fine (I've developed and deployed several Android apps), but I kept noticing that when I suspended and resumed the VM, Delphi suddenly could not find source files, sometimes it could not even see the DPR. These 'File not found' errors are reported across a range of (known good) project source files, seemingly randomly.

I soon discovered that I could cure the problem by restarting the VM OS - everything then worked fine, until the next time I suspended and resumed. This was a nuisance and had never happened with Delphi XE8 in a Windows 8 VM.

So I dug deeper. I've found that upon resuming the VM, the task manager in the VM shows 'Windows Driver Foundation - User mode driver framework host process' at around 16% CPU and about the same % assigned to Seattle. This CPU activity remains without clearing by itself (at least for over 10 minutes). If I terminate the 'Windows Driver Foundation - User mode driver framework host process' manually, my problem goes away without the need for a restart, so I assume that its use of CPU is connected in some way to the File Not Found errors.

Can anyone suggest what connects Delphi with this host process and why it stops on a restart, but is consuming CPU after a VM resume? Is it something to do with Delphi or with one of the mobile SDK's? Basically, what can I turn off or put right?!

Thanks Brian.

Comment: This sounds like it is a driver issue, not a Delphi issue. You need to find out what usermode driver is using the CPU and is being invoked. I use Parallels, not Fusion, and do not see this behaviour - it is possible it is something to do with the VMWare host drivers.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm hazy on drivers but will investigate what tools exist.

Comment: David, it seems you were right. VMWare 10 does not officially support Windows 10, but VMWare 12 does. Upgrading to 12 seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks.